# "Web Attack: Exploit Toolkit Website 32"?

Tags: exploit

What is "Web Attack: Exploit Toolkit Website 32"? 
How do I remove it?
Where is it coming from?
My Norton keeps blocking it.

help me fix my problem Please

Answer (score 2):

A simple web search for "Web Attack: Exploit Toolkit Website 32" returns this page from Symantec (the ones who make your Norton product):

"[Web Attack: Exploit Toolkit Website 32](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/attacksignatures/detail.jsp?asid=26002)"

> **Additional Information**
> Malicious toolkits contain various exploits bundled into a single package. Victim, on visiting the malicious server hosting exploit toolkit, is attacked with several different exploits exploiting different vulnerabilities one by one.
>
> **Response:**
> *No further action is required* but you may wish to perform some of the following actions as a precautionary measure...

Websites you are visiting are infected and they are trying to exploit potential security problems on your computer.  Norton is doing it's job and blocking them, so there's nothing to remove.  The best advice I can give is to avoid those websites.